# Error using Nunit test with WPF Windows app targeting .NET6

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2022

I am using Visual Studio 2022 targeting .NET6 Windows using WPF
When I added Nunit test, I selected .NET 6 as the target.
When I add `using WPF2022ht4fEditor` to my Nunit test I get the error

> Project '..\WPF2022ht4fEditor\WPF2022ht4fEditor.csproj' targets
> 'net6.0-windows10.0.17763.0'. It cannot be referenced by a project
> that targets '.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0'

If I remove the `using` statement, it compiles fine.

How do I fix this?

By the way, I recognize that the problem is that my Nunit test is targeting .NET version 6 and that the application is targeting net6.0-windows. The app .csproj is

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
<OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows10.0.17763.0</TargetFramework>
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
</PropertyGroup>
</Project>`
```

The issue is that I can't find a way to change them so they match. For instance, if I change the .csproj file for the app and set the TargetFramework to net6.0, I get a different error.

Comment: Your test and target projects need to match on compile target. Take a look at what' yoj have set in your csproj xml.

Answer (score 4):

The solution turned out to be extremely simple - change the Unit test to windows

The sequence is
Open Solution Explorer and right click the solution and select "Add" then "new project"
Select Nunit Test Project that runs on ".NET Core on Windows, Linux, and MacOS"
Select Next
Name the Unit test project and click Next
Accept the .NET6.0 Framework option and click Create

Once the Unit test project is loaded, right-click the Unit test project
Scroll to find Target OS
Select Windows

Now you can add the project you want to test.
Right Click on "Dependencies" under the test project
Select "Add project reference"
Select the project to test and press OK
Add "using MyProject" (where MyProject is the name of the project to test)

Note: a reload may be necessary. Close the solution and start it again.

Dave